# How do I get the Row Clicked on, not the Row Selected in a WPF Data Grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, datagrid

I have a column in a DataGrid in XAML that looks like this:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="" Width="35" IsReadOnly="True">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image Source="{Binding PostIcon}" Stretch="None" MouseDown="Post_MouseDown" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

The event that fires is supposed to grab another piece of data in the datagrid row:  In this case, a URL code.  It then runs this when the event is fired:

```
    private void Post_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = ThreadList.SelectedIndex;
        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)ThreadList.SelectedItems[0];

        string topicID = Convert.ToString(row["URL"]);
        string thisURL = "http://www.myforums.com/perm/topic/" + topicID;

        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(thisURL);
    }
```

The idea here is that when you click on an image icon in the data table, it grabs the Index of the row you clicked on, finds the associated thread ID, and builds out the URL and then takes you there.

This all works, except that DataGrid.SelectedItems isn't actually capturing what's clicked on.  It's capturing what's selected at the time of the click.

What this means is that if you click on a row, it always ends up selecting what you had previously clicked on, not what you actually just clicked on.  How do I make it so it selects what I just clicked on?  There doesn't seem to be an obvious 'ClickedItem' equivalent to 'SelectedItems'

**--SOLUTION--**

The full solution I ended up employing, thanks to AnjumSKhan, looks like this (featuring moving the variable 'dc' to an explicit DataRowView variable):

```
    private void Post_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        int index = ThreadList.SelectedIndex;

        var dc = (sender as Image).DataContext;

        DataRowView row = (DataRowView)dc;

        string topicID = Convert.ToString(row["URL"]);
        string thisURL = "http://www.myforums.com/perm/topic/" + topicID;
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(thisURL);
    }
```

Comment: "it always ends up selecting what you had previously clicked on, not what you actually just clicked on. " , what do you mean by this ?

Comment: What is 'selected' and what is 'clicked' are two different things in a WPF DataGrid.  The behavior ends up being such that you can 'select' Row 3 by left clicking on it, and then click on an element in Row 1.  The result will be that any onclick-like event will fire on when you click on your  Row 1 element, but when the code looks at what's actually 'Selected', it will return results from Row 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this :

```
private void Post_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
         var dc = (sender as Image).DataContext;
         ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Handle `MouseLeftButtonUp` event and try this:

```
    private void DataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DependencyObject dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource; 
        while ((dep != null) && !(dep is DataGridRow))
        {
            dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);
        }

        if (dep is DataGridRow)
        {
            DataGridRow row = dep as DataGridRow;
            // do something
        }
    }
```